# Trying to load .env file into to pm2 config - getting error

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, pm2

I have followed every example I can find online and cannot get my pm2 config to correctly load my Node server.  I keept getting the error: `Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv/config'` .  I have my .env in a seperate location from my node server.  I have created the ecosystem.config.js file by following their docs.
Here is the file contents, full directory paths redacted:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name        : "node-server-prod",
    script      : "/my/absolute/path/server.js",
    cwd         : "/my/absolute/path",
    node_args   : "-r dotenv/config",
    args        : "dotenv_config_path=relative/to/cwd/.env"
  }]
}
```

I tried both absolute and relative paths in the args section.  Same with the script path.

I know I have dotenv installed in my node server path.  It is not installed in the directory where my `ecosystem.config.js` file are and where I am calling: `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`.  I am almost certain it would not need to be installed in that directory.  Any help would be much appreciated.